# Проблема с редиректом | Word Press / Debian

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Используя ОС Unix (Debian, Apache)
И вот возникла проблема с WordPress

Когда я делаю ссылку на страницу такого типа site.com/testpage, то когда я перехожу по ней я вижу такую картину

```
Not Found

The requested URL /testpage/ was not found on this server.
```

В директории сайта, то есть /var/www/html/ файл .htcaccess отсутствует

Comment: testpage это директория или файл?

Comment: Это страница которая создана через панель WordPress

Comment: Вебсервер кто - Апач, нжнкс? Укажи это в вопросе.

Answer (score 0):

> В директории сайта, то есть /var/www/html/ файл .htcaccess отсутствует

Это как? На Apache должен быть .htaccess-файл в корне WordPress. Стандартные настройки [здесь](https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess).

Comment: Сейчас сам попробую

Comment: Создал. Безрезультатно 
http://imgur.com/nGNB40S

Comment: Вы ищите свои ошибки прежде всего, читайте внимательно мануалы. Пока что вы очень невнимательно работаете. Что за картинку вы присылаете с **4** буквами w? Вы что, реально хотите на сайте иметь адрес **wwww**? Сильно сомневаюсь.